Python "While not" loop in C
I have written a function in Python that uses a while loop with an inverted condition like this:
while (not x < 0):
 #do something

Is there an elegant solution to map this over to C without having to change the function logic etc?

while(!(x<0)) is the equivalent C construct..?

while (!(x < 0)) ?

But anyway while (x >= 0): would be more readable.

Assuming x can only be a number in the Python code, the following would be equivalent:
while ( ! ( x < 0 ) ) STMT

Of course, it would be far more readable if written as follows:
while ( x >= 0 ) STMT

